# Trouble deserializing generic types using GSON

Tags: java, gson

I have a set of 4 classes which represent my database objects (database is currently only an ArrayList).

I am using GSON to store these objects in a .txt file.

A single class named `Storage` is in charge of reading and writing these objects to those .txt files.

 Here is my problem:
I have a generic object `T extends MyInterface`. That object represents the 4 database classes.
I put `T` in the `Storage` method, so I could use just this one class for any database object.
Here is the code:

```
public class Storage<T extends MyInterface> {

     Gson GSON = new Gson();

     public ArrayList<T> readAll() {
         String objectsJSON = TextFileHandler.readFromFile(fileStorageLocation); // This works
         System.out.println(objectsJSON);   // This also works  (prints out correctly)
         Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>() {}.getType();  
         return GSON.fromJson(objectsJSON, collectionType);     // This fails
     }

}
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to 
interfaces.MyInterface
```

Do you guys have any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of anonymous `TypeToken` subtypes is that they're defined at compile time so that generic type information is saved. You'll need to do something to make the token information available dynamically. [This approach](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeParameter.html) might work:

```
private final TypeToken<ArrayList<T>> targetType;

public Storage(Class<T> dataType) {
    targetType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>(){}
        .where(new TypeParameter<T>(){}, dataType);
}

public List<T> readAll() { // avoid using concrete ArrayList in public API;
                           // not a bad idea to change it in the other locations
    ...
    return GSON.fromJson(objectsJson, targetType);
}
```

Comment: Pardon me for asking, but where can I download the library containing the TypeParameter?

Comment: @ForWiz It's in Guava, the same library that provides `TypeToken`.

Comment: Alright, did it, it works. Thanks a bunch, wouldn't have figured this one out by myself :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use interface `List`, not that implementation as `ArrayList`

```
public List<T> readAll() {
     String objectsJSON = TextFileHandler.readFromFile(fileStorageLocation);
     System.out.println(objectsJSON);
     Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.getType();  
     return GSON.fromJson(objectsJSON, collectionType);
 }
```

If that doesn't work, check `objectJSON` if is correct with JSON format.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately, this didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who might be looking for an answer to this, here's what I exactly did to fix it:

The problem was that GSON did not know which class to instantiate since my `Storage<T>` was used for a couple of different entities. I had to somehow tell it, to which particular entity class was each instance of `Storage<T>` used.
The error I was getting was something like:

`Cannot cast LinkedTreeMap to MyInterface.`

Because at runtime, the `Storage` had no idea which class to instantiate.

I'm doing a regular Java project, so I downloaded the Guava.jar and added it to my project:
http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/guava/guava/23.0/guava-23.0.jar

I modified my generic class `Storage<T>` constructor, to take in the `Class<T> dataType` parameter so it can know at runtime, which class it's being used for.
I also added a private field `TypeToken<List<T>>` so it could store information about the class being deserialized.

Essentially, all I did was this:

```
import com.google.common.reflect.TypeParameter;
import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.*;

public class Storage<T extends MyInterface> {

     // This was used so the Storage objects knows which dataType it's associated to 
     // Because T is deleted at runtime, so you can't use that.
     private TypeToken<List<T>> targetDataType;

     // I changed the constructor to take in 1 bonus argument
     public Storage(Class<T> dataType) {
          targetDataType = new TypeToken<List<T>>() {}
                        .where(new TypeParameter<T>() {}, dataType);            
     }

     public List<T> deserialize() {
         // Read JSON data into a <jsonString> variable
    
         Gson GSON = new Gson();
         return GSON.fromJson(jsonString, targetDataType.getType());
     }
}
```